# Is Vc++ exe file get deleted?

Tags: windows, visual-c++, exe

I am beginner in VC++ developing. I have One doubt. Is exe file get deleted at shut down the machine while the exe is running?

Answer (score 0):

No, the file won't be deleted, it will just be closed.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. After restart the machine , my exe file is deleted. why?

Comment: Is your exe in the debug folder or have you copied it somewhere else?

Comment: I copied in someone folder. exe file path is c:user/AppData/myfolder/first.exe

Comment: I guess it depends on what the file is doing, or what other files are doing to it. VS wouldn't just delete it, so I don't think it is that. Maybe it's an anti virus that is removing it?

Comment: I am using the exe file with Firefox browser. The exe file deleted at only shut down the machine before close the browser. After restart the machine , the exe file is deleted in myfolder.